# JSF ajax event to change value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am trying to change the value of input with JSF ajax request.

I have that JSF code:

```
 <h:inputSecret id="pwd" value="#{info.password}" redisplay="true">
   <f:ajax event="focus" listener="#{info.changePassword}" />
 </h:inputSecret>
```

and the`info` bean contains:

```
public String getPassword() {
    return "";
} 

public void changePassword(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
    UIInput input = (UIInput)e.getComponent();
    input.setValue(createRandomPassword());
}
```

`createRandomPassword()` creates short random string.

But when the inputs get focus, I can see that the `changePassword` function is called and it sets some random string, but the input's value stays empty.

So why `setValue` not set the value to the component? How can I make it works?

Comment: because you nowhere tell it to update the ui side. You just update the server side model. But why not just set create a field called 'password' and set that instead of getting input from the event?

Comment: @Kukeltje I am new with JSF, I thought it will do the job. Can you please show me an example?

Comment: Please start with some **good** tutorials... See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info This is such a basic thing, that reading those will get you informed about this and many more things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-render password input component after setting its value, using render attribute of

```
<h:inputSecret id="pwd" value="#{info.password}" redisplay="true">
   <f:ajax event="focus" listener="#{info.changePassword}" render="pwd"/>
 </h:inputSecret>
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you!